# Road trip from New Delhi to Leh via Manali or Srinagar?

Tags: road-trips, new-delhi, north-india, leh-india

Me and some friends are planning a trip to India and go to Leh from New Delhi by road later this year.

Which route from Delhi to Leh is better out of the two and why?

Comment: Related: [Now that NGT has banned private vehicles from entering the Rohtang pass, what route should I take?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53084/3221)

Comment: Best and most active platform for Leh related travel advice is bcmtouring.com and then maybe indiamike.

Comment: Wow, too many questions.  Please split them up (see [help]).

Comment: You've gone from "too broad" to "too vauge and opinion based".
Most of the original questions were perfectly valid - they were just all mixed together. Ask multiple questions each in their own question thread, and you'll be fine. However, this really vauge "What is best" question is not a good fit for the site and won't get reopened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will find less traffic on Manali route because majority of commercial and defense vehicles use Srinagar route which is also a better quality road. [Srinagar - Leh](https://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/srinagar-leh-highway-nh-1d-the-great-indian-road-trip.571/) route has a lot more options as compared to [Manali - Leh route](https://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/manali-leh-highway-travel-guide.618/) for both accommodation and places to eat. Manali route does not have as many petrol pumps as Srinagar route does. If you do go via Manali, the only large town (not so large) is Keylong and that is the only place in addition to Sarchu where you can find decent accommodation. Srinagar route has plenty of places to stay.